# Display rows that are inside a table to <p> with a textarea under it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a bunch of rows with one column which is QuestionText, the rows can be anything between 1-20 rows depending on how many rows the user add to the table.

Here is my table:

```
<table id="CustomPickedTable" class="box-style2">
        <thead><tr><th>Choosen Questions</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr><td data-row="2">Choosen Data</td></tr>
         <tr><td data-row="1">Choosen data</td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Rows with data in the table can get added/removed by users by another Jquery code.

When a user have choosen what rows she/he wants inside the table, the user clicks on a next button and on this click event I want that all rows inside the tables gets displayed in maby `<p>` with a textarea under it that is readonly. It should display like a Preview for the user and it should be orderby like the table.

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it

**Html**

```
<table id="CustomPickedTable" class="box-style2">
    <thead><tr><th>Choosen Questions</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td data-row="2">Choosen Data</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row="1">Choosen data</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Preview" onclick="preview()" />
<hr />
<div id="test">
</div>​
```

**Javascript**

```
function preview(){
    $('#CustomPickedTable tbody tr td').each(function(){ 
        $('#test').append('<p>'+$(this).text()+'</p><textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>');    
    });
}​
```

Or see my sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VB8Le/2/)

Comment: It worked but I put the JS code in my .click() :) If I would like to remove them all by doing a  button click how would I do that? Remove the <p> and the textareas

Comment: I have updated the link with a new solution. Try it out and tell me if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: since the user can go back and forth in the steps, right now it just duplicates choosen data If a user clicks on next and then goes back one step and removes a row from the table or maby adds rows it just duplicates So I would need some kind of remove on the back button so it always show only the rows that are in the tables

Comment: Example: Lets say I choose to add 4 rows in my table and then I click on next button then everything is perfect I see my 4 rows with a textarea under it. But If I go back one step and add another questions then click on next button I get 4+5 rows on my preview it adds up

Comment: $('#preview').html('') in the onclick handler of the close-button, makes sure the div is empty before you try and populate it again.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you step by step
1.First create a javascript array

2.On each click get the id of that perticular row and put it in the javascript array.

3.Then when next button is clicked use a loop in which all the ids from javascript array will get the rows or whatever kind of data and create table rows putting each ids data into row.